# ¿Como Enviar una Lista por AJAX a un controller en MVC 5?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

me gustaría saber como puedo obtener una lista de objetos en el ajax y enviarlo a ActionResult de mi controlador. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Ajax jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var array=[
        {id: "1", nombre: "Darwin", edad: "26", fecha: "28-10-1992"},
        {id: "2", nombre: "Aldo", edad: "30", fecha: "19-11-1988"},
        {id: "3", nombre: "Alexis", edad: "34", fecha: "01-11-1984"}];

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Prueba/ExportarExcel',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(array),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
```

este es mi controlador la cual quiero almacenarlo en una variable llamada resultado

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportarExcel(List<Persona> array)
{
 var resultado = array;
 return View(resultado.ToList());
}
```

la finalidad de lo que deseo es almacenar los datos del ajax en una lista de objetos de tipo persona como se muestra en el controlador pero me sale un error como este

**El valor no puede ser nulo.\r\nNombre del parámetro: source**

Answer (score 2):

La solución solo era modificar el dataType por el contentType cuando se hacia un post lo comprobe de otra consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias ver que mappen los nombres de los parametros

```
var array=
    { 
        personas:{
            {id: "1", nombre: "Darwin", edad: "26", fecha: "28-10-1992"},
            {id: "2", nombre: "Aldo", edad: "30", fecha: "19-11-1988"},
            {id: "3", nombre: "Alexis", edad: "34", fecha: "01-11-1984"}]
        }
    };
```

asi la propiedad "personas" mapea con el valor de la variable

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportarExcel(List<Persona> personas)
{
   //codigo
}
```

Nota: si aun asi notas que no funciona prueba de quitar el `JSON.stringify()` si defines el tipo de dato como `json` quizas no haga falta

Comment: Ya encontre la solución gracias de todas maneras, el problema era que cuando se hace un post no se usa dataType sino contentType era por ello me mostraba el error null.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con esto en tu script

```
var array=[
    {id: "1", nombre: "Darwin", edad: "26", fecha: "28-10-1992"},
    {id: "2", nombre: "Aldo", edad: "30", fecha: "19-11-1988"},
    {id: "3", nombre: "Alexis", edad: "34", fecha: "01-11-1984"}];

$.ajax({
    url: '/Prueba/ExportarExcel',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(array),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Y de la siguiente manera en tu Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportarExcel([FromBody] Persona array)
{
 var resultado = array;
 return View(resultado.ToList());
}
```